Error processing condition on PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration
I use Spring Cloud 2023.0.0 and Spring Boot 3.2.1 for my microservices. When I run my HelloWorld microserivce I get this error:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration.propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:60) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108) ~[spring-context-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:183) ~[spring-context-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:144) ~[spring-context-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:120) ~[spring-context-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:428) ~[spring-context-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:289) ~[spring-context-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:349) ~[spring-context-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:118) ~[spring-context-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:789) ~[spring-context-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606) ~[spring-context-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:464) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1358) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1347) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at arkadisahakyan.myownmicroservices.helloworld.HelloWorldApplication.main(HelloWorldApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.reactive.ServerHttpSecurityConfiguration] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@2a139a55]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:483) ~[spring-core-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:360) ~[spring-core-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:417) ~[spring-core-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.lambda$getTypeForFactoryMethod$1(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:749) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1708) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:748) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:681) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:652) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1644) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:562) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:534) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:247) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:240) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:230) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:183) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:158) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/reactive/config/WebFluxConfigurer
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3402) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2504) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:465) ~[spring-core-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.reactive.config.WebFluxConfigurer
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ~[na:na]
    ... 37 common frames omitted

My pom.xml for the HelloWorld microservice:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>arkadisahakyan</groupId>
        <artifactId>my-own-microservices</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>arkadisahakyan</groupId>
    <artifactId>hello-world</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>hello-world</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.12.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>0.12.6</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>0.12.6</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>arkadisahakyan.myownmicroservices.helloworld.HelloWorldApplication</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

WebSecurityConfig
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http, JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthFilter, ReactiveAuthenticationManager authManager) {
        return http
                .authorizeExchange(request -> request
                        .pathMatchers("/hello").permitAll()
                        .pathMatchers("/login").authenticated()
                        .pathMatchers("/secured").authenticated()
                        .anyExchange().permitAll())
                .httpBasic(basic -> basic.authenticationManager(authManager))
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .formLogin(form -> form.disable())
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHENTICATION)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails user = User.builder()
                .username("user")
                .password("user")
                .roles("USER")
                .build();
        UserDetails admin = User.builder()
                .username("admin")
                .password("admin")
                .roles("USER", "ADMIN")
                .build();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user, admin);
    }

    @Bean
    public ReactiveAuthenticationManager authenticationManager(UserDetailsService userDetailsService, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        return new ReactiveAuthenticationManagerAdapter(new ProviderManager(authenticationProvider));
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAuthenticationProvider jwtAuthenticationProvider() {
        return new JwtAuthenticationProvider();
    }
}

As you can see I use @EnableWebFluxSecurity. I didn't include the spring-boot-starter-webflux dependency in my pom.xml because it seems the spring-boot-starter-security already includes it. And even if I do include the dependency I encounter with other errors meaning that there are similar beans defined in the context.
There are some answers in StackOverflow on similar questions but none of them solves my problem. I can provide any additional information if needed.

If you want to use webflux you must add a dependency on spring-boot-starter-webflux. Spring security might have a dependency on the jar but not on all the other needed dependencies. You have included spring-boot-starter-web which is weird if you do @EnableWebFluxSecurity as you should either include webflux or use @EnableWebSecurity if not wanting to use webflux.
